# WebClient returns Null in Spring Webflux Project Reactor

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-webclient

Still relatively new to WebFlux.  Liking it, but it can be hard to debug and every once in a while you get a result you weren't expecting.  But hey, that's half the fun.

A problem I have run into relatively recently is Figuring out what to do if you are using Spring WebFlux and WebClient to call a downstream API.

Basically, if you are chaining put calls to update a repository, and each of them returns no content, which translates into a null value at the webclient level.

How do you get your pipeline to subscribe.  I have looked all over the web and can't seem to find a good example on what you should do.

```
public class WackyService {
...
@Autowired
WackyTableApi dbAPIclient
Mono<String> updateDB(WackyRecord record){
 return dbAPIclient.updateWackyTable(record);
}

public class WackyTableApi{
  public void updateWackyTable(WackyRecord wackadoo){
  return webClient
           .put()
           .uri(String.format(url))
           .syncBody(wackadoo)
           .retrieve()
           .onStatus(httpStatus -> {log.info("update WackyTable is not successful for some reason: Statuss reason ->{}", httpStatus.getReasonPhrase() ); return !httpStatus.is2xxSuccessful(); }, CustomExceptionHandler::applyExceptionHandlingLogic)
  }
}
```

The problem is the api returns a 204 on successful puts. Which is not uncommon in rest api design.  But I am doing a zip of this return result with other api calls, and if that result is null, then I believe the zip fails.

What is the standard way of handling this?  Looking around the Web has yielded little results.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Spring Boot Webflux - Mono response when there is no http body, but just http status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67796326/java-spring-boot-webflux-mono-response-when-there-is-no-http-body-but-just-ht)

Comment: This can be useful as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45727372/spring-reactor-mono-zip-fails-on-empty-mono